# Omniauth SAML SubjectConfirmationData is missing child field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml, omniauth, saml-2.0

I'm getting the following error with Omniauth SAML and I don't know how to debug it any further.

```
Authentication failure! invalid_ticket: OneLogin::RubySaml::ValidationError, 6:0: ERROR: Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}SubjectConfirmationData': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}KeyInfo ).
```

I've tried adding skip_receipient_check but that doesn't seem to affect this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in this instance, the customers SAML was invalid and the library did the right thing.